# Command to use curl to add users to a Mastodon list?

Tags: curl, mastodon

I'm moving to a new Mastodon instance and would like to re-create my old lists on my new server. I've tried

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN" https://fosstodon.org/api/v1/lists/LISTID/accounts/?account_ids[]=ACCOUNTID
```

but I'm getting a record not found error. List ID and account ID should be correct. The token is good (I tried a random other string in there and got an authentication error instead). Any thoughts? Thank you.